# Audit unauthenticated accesses to REST APIs

Tags: java, rest, spring-security

I have a RESTful program written entirely in spring. I've used spring security to control REST calls and extended `AccessDeniedHandlerImpl` to audit unauthorized accesses. Now I also want to audit requests from unauthenticated users and log their ip address (the only thing we have, since their username is anonymous). I tried using `AuthenticationEntryPoint` but it doesn't work and prevents redirecting to login page (auditing part works but I can't access my login page and use my program like before).

What is the correct way to implement this behavior? Do I need to implement form login and put auditing in that? Is their a simple listener or something similar for adding logging in my code and showing login page to the user?

This is the code I tried for auditing unauthenticated accesses:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthEntry implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //log user ip and uri they tried accessing 
        resp.sendError(401, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have also registered this implementation in WebSecurityConfig:

```
http
 .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(myAuthEntry);
```

Answer (score -2):

To get the IP address (at least of the last proxy the user came from), use:

```
req.getRemoteAddr()
```

Now if the user is not authenticated, you should send a redirect to the login page, instead of an error.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)

Comment: My question is not about getting ip address. Please read carefully.

Comment: Is it not being able to access the login page? If yes, "please read carefully" the second part of my answer: "Now if the user is not authenticated, you should send a redirect to the login page, instead of an error"

Comment: Please post your answer completely here, instead of posting a link.

Comment: What is the URL pattern you assigned to the login page? Or is it a filter? Without this information I cannot give you a code sample other than `resp.sendRedirect("/your/login/page");`